# 301 Redirect without Query String (Wordpress by htaccess )

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In the past, I had a forum and switched to wordpress
I am trying to convert all forum links without queries to WordPress

For example, I want to login to: https://efhamcomputer.com/?t=123
It is transferred to: https://efhamcomputer.com/

without queries : ?t=123

i tray to add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
RewriteRule (.*) hhttps://efhamcomputer.com/ [L,R=301]
```

but i got error 500

Comment: Comment or remove last `RewriteRule` line.

Comment: not working i tray to remove

Comment: Check your apache error.log to see cause of 500 error

Comment: I just want to remove the query from the link ?t=.. and ransferred to: https://efhamcomputer.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
ewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```

thanks its working fine